# How can I print a dictionary in table format?

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting, pretty-print

Let's say I have a dictionary like:

```
my_dict = {1:[1,2,3],4:[5,6,7],8:[9,10,11]}
```

I want to be able to print it so it looks like:

```
1 4 8
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
```

I'm actually working with much larger dictionaries and it would be nice if I can see how they look since they're so hard to read when I just say `print(my_dict)`

Comment: Why not use the `pprint` module to pretty print?

Comment: I want the keys as the headers and when the dictionary gets really long I would really like to view it as a table..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `zip()` to create columns:

```
for row in zip(*([key] + value for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items()))):
    print(*row)
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_dict = {1:[1,2,3],4:[5,6,7],8:[9,10,11]}
>>> for row in zip(*([key] + value for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items()))):
...     print(*row)
... 
1 4 8
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
```

This *does* assume that the value lists are all of equal length; if not the shortest row will determine the maximum number of rows printed. Use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to print more:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for row in zip_longest(*([key] + value for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items())), fillvalue=' '):
    print(*row)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> my_dict = {1:[1,2,3],4:[5,6,7,8],8:[9,10,11,38,99]}
>>> for row in zip_longest(*([key] + value for key, value in sorted(my_dict.items())), fillvalue=' '):
...     print(*row)
... 
1 4 8
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
  8 38
    99
```

You may want to use `sep='\t'` to align the columns along tab stops.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this doesn't work in python 2.7? Doesn't seem to like either of *row or zip_longest.

Comment: @fantabolous: `zip_longest` is called `izip_longest` in Python 2. `print(*row)` won't work in 2 unless you use `from __future__ import print_function` in your module, or use `print ' '.join(row)`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn for the python 2 conversion. I don't think I actually mentioned *zip anywhere either ;)

Comment: @fantabolous: erm, seems I misread your comment, indeed. Removed that from my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_dict = {1:[1,2,3],4:[5,6,7],8:[9,10,11]}
>>> keys = my_dict.keys()
>>> print(*iter(keys), sep='\t')
8   1   4
>>> for v in zip(*(my_dict[k] for k in keys)): print(*v, sep='\t')
... 
9   1   5
10  2   6
11  3   7
```